# Graphing a simple exponential function

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

As I'm quite new to LaTeX. I wanted to graph the following function

```
F_{(x)} = \dfrac{9}{10}\cdot(-1)^x+1
```

or basically:

[image: Exponential Function]

I tried

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
\addlegendentry{$x^2 - 2x - 1$}
%Here the blue parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10,
    codomain=0:1,
    samples=100,
    ]
    {9/10(-1^(-x)+1)};
\addlegendentry{$x^2 + 2x + 1$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got quite horrible results:
[image: Result]

What could I do to actually make it work?

Comment: The equation you present as an image and the one you implemented are different (sign in the exponent).

Comment: Also the function is complex valued which `pgfplots` cannot handle.  You have to plot real and imaginary part separate.

Comment: What's your definition for `(-1)^x` for real `x`? You can define it for rationals with odd denominator, but is not continuous at any point of the domain. How can you expect it can be drawn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \frac{9}{10} (-1)^x + 1
\intertext{Apply the rules of powers.}
  &= \frac{9}{10} e^{x \ln(-1)} + 1
\intertext{Here $\ln(-1)$ is the complex logarithm}
  \ln(-1) &= \ln(e^{i\pi}) = i \pi
\intertext{One has}
  f(x) &= \frac{9}{10} e^{i \pi x} + 1
\intertext{Split into real and imaginary part:}
  \operatorname{Re}[f(x)] &= \frac{9}{10} \cos(\pi x) + 1 \\
  \operatorname{Im}[f(x)] &= \frac{9}{10} \sin(\pi x)
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x)$},
    domain=-10:10,
    samples=200,
    no markers]
    \addplot { 9/10 * cos(deg(pi*x)) + 1 };
    \addplot { 9/10 * sin(deg(pi*x)) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I prefer `-i\pi` as the logarithm of `-1`? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Well, what if I actually preferred `\ln(-1) = -3 i \pi`?  All branches are beautiful!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the function is only defined for an integer input. But you are trying to plot many more dots in between which are undefined. I have changed the number of samples so that x is always an integer.

It seems to be important to put an explicit `*` between 10 and bracket.

Furthermore I needed to add braces around the `-1` and comment out the `codomain` option (because my system does not know it, maybe I am using an older version than you do).

Also note that this is the function from the code which is different from the one of the screenshot (here the +1 is in brackets).
I have updated the `\addlegendentry`.

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = left,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = {$f(x)$},
        ]
        \addplot [
            domain=-10:10,
            %codomain=0:1,
            samples=21,
            only marks,
        ]
        {9/10*((-1)^(-x)+1)};
        \addlegendentry{$\frac{9}{10}\cdot\left(-1^{-x}+1\right)$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

For a continuous version of the function (from your screenshot, not the code) see [Henri Menke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369936/120953).